Triangle Question Mark Icons In WordPress Text
Ive noticed this little annoying question mark in a couple of spots on my web page at the end of the text.

It's only showing on the mobile atm, not the desktop.
It's showing in two spots only.


Using WordPress 6.5
Twenty Twenty Four theme is enabled
Config File
/** Database charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'  );

I ensured all plugins were up to date and removed plugins I don't plan to use.
I have cleared all cache files.
I'm not sure what else to do, any advise?
Thank you in advance

Where is that text coming from - the theme, or is it part of the post content? If the latter, then you probably have invalid characters after your text, so re-type it properly in the editor.

By the living harry. I didnt even think to retype to stupid thing. That fixed it lol Thanks for help, I feel very dumb right now lol
